# CSS: vertically scroll two absolutely positioned divs while horizontal scrollbar remains fixed

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'm sure I'm going to muddle the explanation of what I'm trying to do, so sorry in advance.

I have two `absolute`ly positioned `<div>` elements right next to each other that are the exact same height, and the one on the right can potentially have horizontal overflow.

When there is horizontal overflow I would like the scrollbar on that `div` (and that `div` only) to remain fixed at the bottom of that `div` while both `divs` continue to scroll vertically together when there is also vertical overflow.

The point being that I want the `div` on the left to remain fixed in its position. Many modern text editors have this feature (pay attention to the scrollbar at the bottom and the column on the left that contains the line numbers):

**Before scrolling:**

[image]

**After scrolling HORIZONTALLY:**

[image]

**After scrolling VERTICALLY:**

[image]

the line numbers on the left stay fixed, regardless of how far to the right you scroll, but they scroll vertically with the page and the horizontal scrollbar is always available.

I've been playing with every combination of relative/absolute positioned container elements to try and solve this problem, but I've been coming up short. Here is my most recent attempt though:

```css
#div1
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 150%;
 width: 60px;
 background: black;
}

#outer
{
 position: fixed;                                                                                           
 left: 0; 
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 top: 0;
 overflow-x: auto;
}

#div2
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 150%;
 background: grey;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}

#div2-wrapper
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 60px;
 height: 50%;
}

#div1-wrapper
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 50%;
 width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
 <div id="div1-wrapper">
  <div id="div1">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="div2-wrapper">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I would like to avoid using jQuery if it's possible, but I also have that available if it comes to it.

Edit: to clarify, there are three requirements I'm trying to satisfy. 1: the div on the left must always remain in its starting position horizontally (scrolling left or right does not move it), 2: the div on the left must scroll vertically with the div beside it, 3: if there is horizontal overflow in the right-hand div, the scrollbar for it must always remain at the bottom of the screen. Gooogle Sheets and Excel do it too with row numbers.

Comment: Did you try to put your first div (div1-wrapper) in position fixed ? If I understand correctly, it's just what you need.

Comment: Yeah I tried that. It didn't seem to help.

Comment: I suggest you to minimize and simplify your question. I know it is not hard problem, but I can not understand what you want.

Comment: Can you give us another real-world example (like the code editor window) of the end goal? What are you actually trying to create? I can't wrap my head around your description.

Comment: You can't have both horizontal and vertical scrollbars at the same time on the same element. I'm guessing you want a wrapper with a horizontal scroll that contains two columns; a fixed one and one that has a vertical scroll. Could you please confirm that is what you mean?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Not quite. I want both columns to scroll vertically in sync with one another, and I do not want the first column to disappear if you scroll to the right.

Comment: There are three requirements I'm trying to satisfy. 1: the div on the left must always remain in its starting position horizontally (scrolling left or right does not move it), 2: the div on the left must scroll vertically with the div beside it, 3: if there is horizontal overflow in the right-hand div, the scrollbar for that must always remain at the bottom of the window. Gooogle Sheets and Excel do it too with row numbers.

Comment: @JimmyP did you figure out the solution to this ? I am trying to solve the same problem. I have found this link which is close enough : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66386961/position-fixed-in-child-element-but-sync-parents-x-scroll-with-child-elements-le

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be what you want :
https://jsfiddle.net/pwo678ks/

I'm position the two columns next to each other with display: flex on the parent (but you could use float: left if you prefer). Then, the parent is scrolling vertically, and the second div alone is scrolling horizontally. If the line-height is the same in the 2 divs, you should be fine.

Edit : And you can remove the divs inside the wrappers.

```
#outer
{
  display: flex;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow-x: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#div1-wrapper, #div2-wrapper
{
  height: 100%;
}

#div2-wrapper
{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#div1-wrapper
{
    width: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Not quite. I want the horizontal scrollbar to essentially remain fixed as you scroll vertically. If you add a bunch more breaks to column 2 in your example, you'll see that you have to scroll down to see the horizontal scrollbar. I want that scrollbar to always be at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you will have to use JavaScript. Either you use JavaScript to create a fixed scrollbar at the bottom to scroll horizontally, or use JavaScript to scroll the left bar when you scroll on the right vertically (and your 2 divs will need to have a height of 100vh). I think the second solution would be easier, for the first one you will have to make calculation for the fake scrollbar to work correctly.